Image references when using Langchain's PyPDFLoader
I would like to import text from PDFs with langchain's PyPDFLoader and have images replaced with a text reference. I want to export the images as files and retrieve them using the reference.
Is there any way to have placeholders for images included in the extract?

Hi, I find that PDFplumber (https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber) gives you the most flexibility to to it. You can extract every bit of text and images while having access to their coordinates (and other metadata). You can then do whatever you want with these elements.
